# Partitions are mounted under /media/user1/ even for user2, who cannot access them

Tags: permissions, mount

Ubuntu 22.10 and Cinnamon.

Say we have two users: *Admin* and *Standard*.

There are a few external disk partitions that are mounted at startup (no changes to default Disks settings).

*Admin* logs in. Partitions are mounted under `/media/Admin/Partition`.

Then, *Standard* user logs in. Perhaps *Admin* logged off, or they simply "switched".

*Standard* user is now offered (by Nemo, I guess) all the same external disk partitions mounted.

But: **these partitions are still mounted under `/media/Admin/Partition` and *Standard* user cannot access them!**

This is confusing. I though Ubuntu (or should I say Nautilus/Nemo?) would install partitions under the `/media/username` scheme?? **Shouldn't this change accordingly to what user is logged in?**

Even more confusing: *Standard* user at this point can enter Disks and, with the *Admin* password, change the mount point to one accessible to them.

When *Admin* logs back in, however, the mount point has been changed, and things are not where they were supposed to be!

How could this be happening? What am I missing?

**How to make partitions equally accessible for two different users, regardless of who mounted the partition first, or their status?**

Should all mounting paths be changed to something generic such as `/mnt/`? Or would the permissions problem be the same?

EDIT: the problem remains if both users are administrators.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 did not have *Cinnamon* as a *flavor* before Ubuntu Cinnamon 23.04, so are you using Ubuntu? or the Ubuntu Cinnamon 22.10 *respin*?  If you want mounts to be used by both users, don't use a GUI feature to mount them (*and have them linked to that user*) but define set mount points & have them auto-mounted, or just on request and in a location where you decide is appropriate for both users. There are many ways to accomplish this, but I'd use the *file-system table* for the OS; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: Ubuntu, cinnamon... Wouldn't these problems be equally repeatable under regular Ubuntu? Editing fstab, okay... but, isn't that what Disks is for?